# problems in Perl script with localized user name on Windows

Tags: windows, perl, shell

I have a perl script to start a script file with default program.

```
system("Start C:\\Temp\\test.jsx");
```

It works file with English user names but when I change user name to aiЦ中 it doesn't work.

Also no error message appears to I'm not able to debug.

Comment: How are user names involved?

Comment: So where are the usernames? in the .jsx file? this is pretty vague.

Comment: no usernames are not involved in .jsx files or other scripts? but the script only fails for usernames with 4byte and 2 byte characters so i guess this has to do something with the username.

Comment: Whose username are you talking about? The user that's logged in and is running the script?

Comment: sounds more like a permissions error than username error. Does the user `aiЦ中` have the same permissions on the system than the other user?

Comment: yes, when i login as aiabc (or some other user) scripts work fine, but when i use localized user names ( japense or korean) like aiЦ中 it doesn't work.

Comment: yes, they're in same group "Administrators".

Comment: what is inside the .jsx file?

Comment: code to execute test cases on Illustrator, this command start illustrator and execute test cases written in .jsx file.

Comment: can you show some of the content?

Comment: var AutomationScriptManagerAutomatedMode = false;
try
{var AutomationScriptManager = new Object;
AutomationScriptManager.getBVTTier1ScriptsFolder = function (){var scriptsFolder = null;
     var devScriptsFolder = null; .................

Comment: So wheres the perl code here ?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle the line with `system`.

Comment: @Divyank I honestly cannot see how the user you are logged on can cause this issue. Can you try this please and see if this outputs any messages? `$line = \`C:\\Temp\\test.jsx\`; print $line;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`perl` on Windows uses so called ANSI functions to interface with the outside world. That means, if you use interesting characters (for example, certain Turkish letters on a US-English Windows install), `perl` cannot see them. As [I wrote on my blog](https://www.nu42.com/2017/02/perl-unicode-windows-trilogy-one.html):

> You can't pass characters that are outside of the Windows code page to `perl` on the command line. It doesn't matter whether you have set the code page to 65001 and use the `-CA` command line argument to `perl`: Because `perl` uses `main` instead of `wmain` as the entry point, it never sees anything other than characters in the ANSI code page.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> $ chcp 65001
> $ perl -CAS -E "say for @ARGV" şey
> sey
> ```
>
> That's because `ş` does not appear in `CP 437` which is what my laptop is using. By the time it reaches the internals of `perl`, it has already become `s`.

So, there is not much you can do with a stock `perl`. I was working on a set of patches, but things intervened. I may still get around to it this summer.

Now, in your case, you are passing "interesting characters" to an external program via `system`. The same problem applies. Because `perl` is using the ANSI versions of functions used to spawn processes etc, the program spawned will not see a Unicode environment. So, if you are trying to use Korean or Japanese programs with a system code page that does not include them, I am not sure what will happen.

There is not much you can do once `perl` is running. The environment, command line arguments, everything lives in the ANSI world from that point on. There may be funky work-arounds, but for that one would need to know exactly how `'aiЦ中'` gets from your `perl` program to the external program.